# How to add auto parentheses when create object in Kotlin (Intelij Idea)

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

In Java when I create object, parentheses are auto added but in Kotlin it's not happening. How can I fix it?

Java:

```
Person person = new Person();
```

Kotlin:

```
val person = Person
```

Comment: They are autoadded. I started write `var string: String = S...` and from hint I chosed `String() (kotlin)`. It's not too convenient. Default first choice is `String (kotlin)`

Comment: It works for String but not for my custom class

Comment: It's my hint for Person https://imgur.com/a/8blMXcR and my hint for String https://imgur.com/a/NF9A9PN, String works like in Java with auto parentheses

Comment: Add type explicitly: `val person: Person =`

Comment: Yes it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000759070-How-to-change-IntelliJ-suggested-list-order

And first post by Serge Baranov: It remembers your last choices, just complete the different choice several times.

Add type explicitly: `val person: Person =`

It worked for me for `String` because `String()` was not default. It also worked for custom `Person` class.